# How to use customised control in windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a drop down list in my windows form having banks name and my requirements is to design cheque in windows form that needs to print using crystal report... I came to know we can set the margins using customised controls...How to use the customised controls in windows form and what is the purpose of customised controls..

Comment: You are talking about winForms then why you tagged the post with `asp.net`?

Comment: Wrongly tagged..

Comment: you can design 3 controls as,
01) Drop Down - to select Bank
02) TextBox1 - to get lower margin for Check
03) TextBox2 - to get Higher margin for Check

pass all the three values as parameters to your sql query or to your Crystal Report, i don't think you need custom control for your requirement

Comment: I want to show my cheque preview design in winforms....

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created your customized control and compiled the project it should show up in your toolbox under a heading correlating to your project name. Simply drag it to your form like you would any other control.

The purpose of custom controls is to encapsulate more complex functionality and reuse it over and over. For example. If you wanted to input 100 3D coordinates using individual NumericUpDown controls that would be a lot of work to set up 300 controls and map them to the individual properties of the data objects. Instead you can create a custom control consisting of 3 NumericUpDown controls that can bind to a Point3D Object directly.

Comment: how to use these control in my program....can you provide me sample code.....How to use ?

Answer (score 0):

create your form with TableLayout panel and create UserControl with 3 labels
add all your Bank details to a List, add them to the table with foreach loop

```
private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
                            var uc = new CustomControl();
                foreach (var detail in CheckDetails)
                    {                       

                            var uc = new CustomControl();

                            uc.lblBankName.Text=detail.BankName;
                            uc.lblLowerLimit.Text=detail.LLimit;
                            uc.lblHigherLimit.Text=detail.HLimit;
                            var temp = tbl_BankDtls.RowStyles[tbl_BankDtls.RowCount - 1];
                            tbl_BankDtls.RowCount++;
                            tbl_BankDtls.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 35));                            
                            tbl_BankDtls.Controls.Add(uc, 0,0);
                            this.Height += 40;
                            this.MinimumSize = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
                    }
        }
```

Comment: is it third party  control....If yes means, where will i get the reference file for custom control....and what is the namespace...because it's throwing error...

Comment: No its not a third party control its just an usercontrol you can add by,
right click Project(solution explorer) -> add -> UserControl
design this as you require and add this to your main form dynamically with the above code snippet

Comment: these 3 label controls and table layoutpanel  has to been in customcontrol or windows form?

Comment: Labels are to be designed in your custom control and that custom control to be used within your winform ( which contains TableLayoutPanel )

Answer (score 0):

```
Form1 : (Form1.cs)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BankDetails_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var uc = new BankDtls();
            uc.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom);
            //uc.lblBankName.Text = detail.BankName;
            //uc.lblLowerLimit.Text = detail.LLimit;
            //uc.lblHigherLimit.Text = detail.HLimit;
            //var temp = tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1];
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40));
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(uc, 0, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);
            tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(uc, 3);
            this.Height += 40;
            this.MinimumSize = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
        }
    }
}


Form1 ( Designer.cs )
namespace BankDetails_Test
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(306, 42);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Add Another";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 3;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33334F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33334F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label3, 2, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label2, 1, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label1, 0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 30F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 0F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(376, 31);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
            this.label1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(115, 20);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Bank Name";
            this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(130, 5);
            this.label2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(115, 20);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.label2.Text = "Lower Margin";
            this.label2.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(255, 5);
            this.label3.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(116, 20);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.label3.Text = "Higher Margin";
            this.label3.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(393, 70);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    }
}



BankDtls - UserControl (BankDtls.Designer.cs)
namespace BankDetails_Test
{
    partial class BankDtls
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.numericUpDown1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
            this.numericUpDown2 = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numericUpDown1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numericUpDown2)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 3;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.numericUpDown2, 2, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1, 0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.numericUpDown1, 1, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(332, 31);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // comboBox1
            // 
            this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "Bank ABC",
            "Bank XYZ",
            "Bank DSH"});
            this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
            this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 21);
            this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // numericUpDown1
            // 
            this.numericUpDown1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(113, 3);
            this.numericUpDown1.Name = "numericUpDown1";
            this.numericUpDown1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 20);
            this.numericUpDown1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // numericUpDown2
            // 
            this.numericUpDown2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(223, 3);
            this.numericUpDown2.Name = "numericUpDown2";
            this.numericUpDown2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 20);
            this.numericUpDown2.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // BankDtls
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
            this.Name = "BankDtls";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(340, 39);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numericUpDown1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numericUpDown2)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown numericUpDown2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown numericUpDown1;
    }
}
```

i have tried somethink like this please try the above mentioned code